# Getting error in using ECDSA

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin, ecdsa

We have a function:

```
function _validSignature(bytes memory signature, bytes32 msgHash) internal view returns (bool) {
        return msgHash.toEthSignedMessageHash().recover(signature) == _signerAddress;
    }
```

As i know `toEthSignedMessageHash()` takes `messageHash` as argument and `recover()` takes `messageHash` and `signature` as argument. But i did not understand how writing code like this:`msgHash.toEthSignedMessageHash().recover(signature)` working. Can you explain me this?
When i tried same thing like this:

```
function recoverAddress(bytes32 _hash) public returns(address recovered){
        bytes32 signature = ECDSA.toEthSignedMessageHash(_hash);
        recovered = ECDSA.recover(_hash, signature);
        return recovered;
    }
```

its giving error for `ECDSA.recover()`.

Error:

```
Member "recover" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in type(library ECDSA).
```

Why? Why my approach giving error?

Answer (score 0):

`msgHash.toEthSignedMessageHash().recover(signature)` works because you're attaching the ECDSA library's functions to `bytes32`.

This line:

```
using ECDSA for bytes32
```

will make it so everytime you have `bytes32var.someFunction(otherArgs)`, the compiler will interpret it like `ECDSA.someFunction(bytes32var, otherArgs)`.

---

This function:

```
    function recoverAddress(bytes32 _hash) public returns(address recovered){
        bytes32 signature = ECDSA.toEthSignedMessageHash(_hash);
        recovered = ECDSA.recover(_hash, signature);
        return recovered;
    }
```

is giving you error cause there's no `recover` function that takes `(bytes32, bytes32)` as arguments. You probably meant to write something like:

```
    function recoverAddress(bytes memory signature, bytes32 msgHash) public returns(address recovered){
        bytes32 _message = ECDSA.toEthSignedMessageHash(msgHash);
        recovered = ECDSA.recover(_message, signature);
        return recovered;
    }
```

Comment: `toEthSignedMessageHash()` returns the signature, right? so why do we need to pass signature as argument?

Comment: @Hacek nah, it returns another hash https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/cryptography/ECDSA.sol#L165